# how to use two arrays or three arrays in the foreach loop in php for insert to database

Tags: php, arrays, explode, implode

How to insert multiple arrays with a foreach in rows of databases?

It's not a problem with an array, but my problem is to use two arrays or more.

my php code:

```
$checkBox1 = implode(',', $_POST['goinput1']);
$checkBox2 = implode(',', $_POST['goinput3']);
$mark3=explode(',', $checkBox1);
$mark4=explode(',', $checkBox2);
foreach($mark3 as $out3) 
{
    $sql_sub = "INSERT INTO sub_forms
                        (bord_mizban,bord_mihman) 
                VALUES ('$out3','$out4')";      
    if ($conn->query($sql_sub) === TRUE) {  

    } else {

    }   

}
```

**
**I want the out 4 variable insert to the database with the out 3 variable**
**

Comment: Please clarify, I do not understand what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @Rust I want to use two arrays or three arrays in the foreach loop

Comment: What is the relationship between $mark3 and $mark4?
Are they the same length (do they contain the same number of elements)?

Comment: @dearsina There is no relationship and they are completely separate. The name of the guest team and the host team are carried as strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over `$mark3` using indexes (`$key`) and get element under same key:

```
foreach($mark3 as $key => $out3) 
{
    echo $out3 . '; ' . $mark4[$key];
}
```

Comment: Can you explain more? This code does not work or my knowledge is low for use.

Comment: Here's a sample code https://3v4l.org/gaeKv I don't know __your__ values of `$mark3` and `$mark4`.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is:

```
foreach($mark3 as $key => $out3) {
    $values = "'$out3."','".$mark4[$key]."'"
    $sql_sub = "INSERT INTO sub_forms
                        (bord_mizban,bord_mihman) 
                VALUES ($values)";      
    if ($conn->query($sql_sub) === TRUE) {  

    } else {

    }   

}
```

That would fix your actual question.  However, there is a better way to do this,  with only 1 sql query.

```
foreach($mark3 as $key => $out3) {
    $valuesArray[] = "('$out3."','".$mark4[$key]."')" // this makes an array of your value sets.
}
$values = join(", ", $valuesArray) // this joins your array to one string, with each entry separated by a comma.
$sql_sub = "INSERT INTO sub_forms
                        (bord_mizban,bord_mihman) 
                VALUES $values";      
    if ($conn->query($sql_sub) === TRUE) {  

    } else {

    }
```